# Search 'clear button' javascript issue in filterable table

Tags: javascript, search, filter, html-table

I am making a filterable table of complex data that can be filtered by both category (select option) and by search (input text field). I am having an issue when a search 'category' is selected, and i begin to use the search input. When I click the 'x' that appears in the search box to clear the content, the table doesn't return the full 'category' table. Mostly clicking the clear 'x' either does nothing, or in some returns a strange selection of table rows.

The below is dummy content, but I've copy and pasted the actual table content within this code and am getting the same issue.

Can anybody help me to find the code that corrects the search clear 'x' that appears once I start typing to return either the full table if the category is set to 'all', of the full table filtered by the appropriate category selection, if one has been selected?

Thanks so much!

```
    <div class="container">

    <h2>Finder</h2>


     <div class="step1">
        <p>Show category:</p>
     </div>

     <select type="search" class="select-table-filter" data-table="order-table" id="searchInput">
        <option value="">All</option>  
        <option value="1">1</option>  
        <option value="2">2</option>  
        <option value="3">3</option>  

     </select>

<input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Search ..." />
<table class="order-table" id="myTable">
   <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>Taylor</td>
         <td>Swift</td>
         <td>1234 5678</td>
         <td>taytay@gmail.com</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>John</td>
         <td>Smith</td>
         <td>1234 5678</td>
         <td>johnnyboy@gmail.com</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>Jane</td>
         <td>Doh</td>
         <td>1234 5678</td>
         <td>dohnut@gmail.com</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>Taylor</td>
         <td>Doh</td>
         <td>1234 5678</td>
         <td>td@gmail.com</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

And the script ...

```
(function(document) {
'use strict';

var LightTableFilter = (function(Arr) {

var _input;
var _select;

    /***** FUNCTION FOR SEARCH INPUT *****/
    function _onInputEvent(e) {
        _input = e.target;
        var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
        Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
            Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
                Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
            });
        });
    }




    /***** INPUT CODE TO SEARCH ONLY FIRST COLUMN *****/
    function _onSelectEvent(e) {
          var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
          txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }       
      }
    }


    function _filter(row) {
        var input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
        var category = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent;
        var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
        row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : ((filter === '' || category === filter) && 'table-row');
}


    return {
        init: function() {
            var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
            var selects = document.getElementsByClassName('select-table-filter');
            Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
                input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
            });
            Arr.forEach.call(selects, function(select) {
                select.onchange  = _onSelectEvent;
            });
                }
            };
        })(Array.prototype);

        document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
            if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
                LightTableFilter.init();
            }
        });


        })(document);
```

Comment: The ```x``` is to clear the input field only, and it will not clear the select box value so you will get the values as per the previously selected one in select box .. This is working expected only right? Can you come up with some clarity in what is your expectation exactly??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan that's what I expected, but it doesn't seem to unfilter when the 'x' is clicked and the text input returns to empty. I want it the category to remain, but the full category table to show again once the text input is cleared. 

Do you know of a way to reset the search? It is working when 'all' category is selected, but not when any other category is selected. Could the script be referencing the option value?

Comment: Even if you clear the input, it will still take reference of what you have already selected in select box and will give you the result of that selection which already works.. Could you please mention what is your expected result exactly.. Sorry I am still not clear with your question.. I have replicated your code here, https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/RwPRaJG .. If possible explain what should i need to do in this link to reproduce your issue??

Comment: or it may be in this bit
`function _filter(row) {
            var input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
            var category = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent;
            var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
            row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : ((filter === '' || category === filter) && 'table-row');
  }`

Comment: Hey @ManirajMurugan I figured it out it using the following: 
`function _filter(row) {
            var input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
            var category = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent;
            var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
            row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : ((filter === '' || category.includes(filter)) && 'table-row');
    
    
  }`

The category === filter if statement was too specific.